# AFNetworking redirect to another server when first server get failed

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, web-services, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking for server side operations and it working fine but now I want such type of implementation where if my first server fail to respond from any reason (server failure, ssl error or something like that) than the request should be redirect to another server.

For example like we have server abc.com and the request fail due to any reason than it should request to xyz.com and try to get response. Here abc.com and xyz.com both have the same data and xyz.com is a backup server.
how can I implement this?

Comment: You could check for the response code and if it's something else than 200, you can do another request on the backup server. Also, in the case when server is not reachable, it will throw an exception. You can catch this exception and send the request again to the backup server.